# Speed up large calculation of intersections

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

I have the following data:

1. `trains` is a dictionary with 1700 elements. The keys are the IDs of trains and the value for each train is an array with every station ID where that train stops.
2. `departures` is a dictionary with the same keys as `trains`, so also 1700 elements. Each value is the departure time of the train.

Now, I would like to compute intersections between trains. When train A and train B have overlapping stops, I look at the departure time of both trains. When train A departs before train B, then (A, B) is put in the resulting set, otherwise (B, A).

```
trains = {90: [240, 76, 18, ...], 91: [2, 17, 98, 76, ...], ...}
departures = {90: 1418732160, 91: 1418711580, ...}
intersections = []

for i in trains:
    trA = trains[i]
    for j in trains:
        if i != j:
            trB = trains[j]
            intersect = [val for val in trA if val in trB]
            if intersect:
                if departures[i] < departures[j]:
                    if (i, j) not in intersections:
                        intersections.append((i, j))
                else:
                    if (j, i) not in intersections:
                        intersections.append((j, i))
```

When finished, the intersections list contains 500.000 elements.

This however takes very long to compute! I'm guessing it is because of the `(i, j) not in intersections` and `(j, i) not in intersections` statements.

Is there any way I could alter my code to speed up this calculation?

Comment: How dense are the `trains` and `depaturs` dictionaries? (What is the maximum key?)

Comment: Why do you want to compute a set of pairs of trains that have a stop in common? What are you going to do with this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over `.items()`:

```
for i, trA in trains.items():
    for j, trB in trains.items():
        if i != j:
```

You should probably do an early `continue` instead.

To calculate `intersect`, use sets:

```
for i, trA in trains.items():
    trA_set = set(trA)

    for j, trB in trains.items():
        if i == j:
            continue

        intersect = trA_set.intersection(trB)
```

This swaps an \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ operation for an \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ one.

You only check for is-empty, so this can be swapped with:

```
if trA_set.isdisjoint(trB):
    continue
```

Then you do

```
if departures[i] < departures[j]:
    if (i, j) not in intersections:
        intersections.append((i, j))
else:
    if (j, i) not in intersections:
        intersections.append((j, i))
```

This can be simplified by making `intersections` a set, as long as order isn't important:

```
intersections = set()

...

if departures[i] < departures[j]:
    intersections.add((i, j))
else:
    intersections.add((j, i))
```

or even

```
route = (i, j) if departures[i] < departures[j] else (j, i)
intersections.add(route)
```

Note that this still requires doing everything both ways. It would be simpler to require a given ordering at the start:

```
for i, trA in trains.items():
    trA_set = set(trA)
    for j, trB in trains.items():
        if i == j or departures[i] > departures[j]:
            continue

        if trA_set.isdisjoint(trB):
            continue

        intersections.add((i, j))
```

Note that you should probably stick to PEP 8:

```
for i, tr_a in trains.items():
    tr_a_set = set(tr_a)
    for j, tr_b in trains.items():
        if i == j or departures[i] > departures[j]:
            continue

        if tr_a_set.isdisjoint(tr_b):
            continue

        intersections.add((i, j))
```

Comment: You could update the loop to only go over the necessary indexes (i.e. the inner one should start at `i+1`) similarly to how @AJMansfield structured the `pairs` function.

Comment: @ferada Unfortunately, dictionaries aren't sliceable. I could make an intermediate list, but I doubt it would significantly speed things up seeing as the main cost is probably `tr_a_set.isdisjoint(tr_b)`. Using `itertools.combinations` also prevents the `trA_set = set(trA)` optimization.

Comment: But the `keys` return value would be sliceable; in any case I'm pretty sure that not doing \$n^2\$ for the outer two loops is a good idea.

Comment: @ferada On Python 2, yes, but I don't think I can assume that. Anyway, `combinations(..., 2)` is still \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a somewhat different algorithm to accomplish this task, by instead making a dictionary of all trains that go to each stop, sorting those trains by arrival, and then taking all inorder pairs of trains at each stop.

The basic algorithm is like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

trains = {...}
departures = {...}

intersections = set()

stations = defaultdict(list)
for t, train in trains.items():
    for s in train:
        stations[s].append(t)

for station in stations.values():
    intersections.update(combinations(sorted(station, key=lambda t: departures[t]), 2))
```

(This version of the code vastly improved by @Veedrac)

Comment: Could you explain your code a bit more in depth? I don't really see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools.combinations(…, 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) is a handy way to consider all pairs just once.  Based on the @ferada's follow-up comments to @Veedrac's answer…

```
from itertools import combinations

train_sets = {train_id: set(stops) for train_id, stops in trains}
for (i, i_stops), (j, j_stops) in combinations(train_sets.items(), 2):
    if not i_stops.is_disjoint(j_stops):
        intersections.add((i, j) if departures[i] < departures[j] else (j, i))
```